# Where is the path of network folders?

Tags: xubuntu, samsung

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. Recently my Samsung TV detects my laptop on the network and shows some folders that I couldn't find on the laptop.

Where is the path of these folders?

[image: picture of the folders]

Comment: The screenshot says "root". Are you connecting to the root account of your Laptop? How did you do that ?!

Comment: @RoVo It might mean the root directory of the shared folders.

Comment: If you open the folders on the TV, do they contain any files?

Comment: What happens when you select "Browse folders"? @RoVo I guess it refers to the root of the (accessible) filesystem.

Comment: @RoVo no I just use my regular user

Comment: @wjandrea No folders are empty

Comment: @danzel it's empty